# Delete certain parts of json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'd like to create a new JSON array based on certain values.

Sample JSON:

```
var array = 
{
    "entries": {
         "houses": [
              {
                 "category": {
                     "category_id":"1",
                     "category_foo":"bar",
                  },
                  "important": {
                      "important_foo":"bar",
                      "dontforget":"me",
                  }
               },
               {
                 "category": {
                     "category_id":"1",
                     "category_foo":"bar",
                  },
                  "important": {
                      "important_foo":"bar",
                      "dontforget":"me",
                  }
               },
                 "category": {
                     "category_id":"2",
                     "category_foo":"bar",
                  },
                  "important": {
                      "important_foo":"bar",
                      "dontforget":"me",
                  }
               }
            ]
       }
}
```

Now I need a way to search through this array and create a new array with all `houses` that have a `category` with `category_id=1`. Of course it should keep all the rest of the infos like `important`.

The new array should look like:

```
{
    "entries": {
         "houses": [
              {
                 "category": {
                     "category_id":"1",
                     "category_foo":"bar",
                  },
                  "important": {
                      "important_foo":"bar",
                      "dontforget":"me",
                  }
               },
               {
                 "category": {
                     "category_id":"1",
                     "category_foo":"bar",
                  },
                  "important": {
                      "important_foo":"bar",
                      "dontforget":"me",
                  }
               }
            ]
       }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it would help if you provided some  code on what you have tried, or atleast thought about trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works.

```
var houses = array.entries.houses;
var newHouses = [];
for (var i = 0; i < houses.length; i++)
{
     if (houses[i].category.category_id == "1") {
     newHouses.push(houses[i]);
     }
}
```

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/2u13phw3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter` to do this:

```
var filteredResults = array.entries.houses.filter(function(house) {
    return house.category && house.category_id == 1;
});
```

Comment: looks like category_id is a string.

Comment: @DanielA.White -- Yeah, should be fine. `"1" == 1`